# Website not running on Ubuntu after installing LAMP Stack

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I did it... I moved to Ubuntu today for the first time. I've been loyal to Windows for quite a while, but here I am. Anyway, I'm not used to all the command line tools and I'm facing some trouble with some essential parts of my work in this new environment.

I have installed the LAMP Stack via these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tasksel
$ sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Now I have the latest PHP, Apache, MySQL. I've also installed phpMyAdmin to this group via:

```
$sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I have created a file on `var/www` with a simple `phpinfo()` and it's working alright. However, when I've loaded my project into a new directory inside `var/www` - I'm getting nothing back. Just a blank white page.

My website has been working correctly on Windows via XAMPP and it is also running fine on my VPS online, but here on my new system... Nothing.

What could be wrong with my configuration? How can I debug this issue?

I need my website working locally so I can continue my work here.

Comment: Kinda hard to answer when we know nothing about your project, how you copied it, how you ran it,  etc. Could you clarify?

Comment: It was the permissions. I had to edit the permissions to allow execution of the website files. I didn't know this was needed, but I figured it out at last.

Comment: Could you add an answer below with the steps you took? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my files were not accessible after copying them over from a Windows system to Ubuntu. Having this said, I had to modify the permissions of my project directory to 766. I did this with the following command:

```
chmod -R 766 /My/Directory/Path/
```

After this my files were showing up normally in the web browser.